# Add Flag image in Google Translate

Tags: jquery, css, google-translate

How to add a flag for each country in google tranaslate?

[image]

So far I have done below code but nothing works.

Using CSS

```
.goog-te-menu2-item::before {
content:'';
background: url('de.png'); 
height: 16px; 
width: 33px; 
}
```

Using jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    var divCheckingInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var lang = $('.goog-te-menu2-item');
        if(lang.length > 0){
            $('.goog-te-menu2-item').prepend("<img src='de.png'>");
            clearInterval(divCheckingInterval);         
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

HTML of Google translate

[image]

Code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="google_translate_element" ></div>
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    </p>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit()
        {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement(
                {
                    pageLanguage: 'de',
                    includedLanguages: 'nl,en,fr,de,it,es',
                    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE 
                },
                'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It's basically impossible to style the options dropdown of a select element. You'll have to implement your own - for example it probably won't even let you choose a font let alone add before pseudo element to an option.

Comment: @AHaworth it is not a select element, but anchor tags and span inside it see my updated question.

Comment: I must have picked up an old version. Can you make a runnable snippet? In particular how does google style those items?

Comment: check the updated question I have added the actual code I am using to load google translate.

Comment: I guess you've discovered that the drop down list is actually a set of anchor elements within just one cell in an HTML table which is within an iframe. i.e. not exposed in a way you can just add CSS to.